# How to find out the systemd version on Raspbian

Tags: linux, systemd, raspbian

How can I find the systemd version that came as part of my linux (raspbian) installation?

On running *lsb_release -a*, I get the linux (raspbian) version information as follows

> Distributor ID:   Raspbian
>   Description:  Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
>   Release:  9.1
>   Codename: stretch

Comment: Downvoted because no effort was shown to answer a basic question which has basically the same answer for most any software package. The answer is even right in "man systemd" if you search in there for "version".

Answer (score 37):

Ask it:

```
$ /sbin/init --version
systemd 123

$ systemctl --version
systemd 123
```

You can also ask the package manager:

```
$ dpkg -l systemd
||/ Name              Version       Architecture  Description
+++-=================-=============-=============-========================================
ii  systemd           123-1         amd64         system and service manager
```

If you think the files might have been upgraded since, you can ask the running process:

```
$ busctl --system get-property org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
                               /org/freedesktop/systemd1 \
                               org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager \
                               Version
s "123"
```

Comment: On Raspbian Stretch Lite, I get `/sbin/init: unrecognized option '--version'`.  Even though the man page says this is a valid option.

Comment: On many systems, `/sbin/init` is a symbolic link to `../lib/systemd/systemd` and the `--version` option is recognized only if the binary is called directly like  `/lib/systemd/systemd --version`